# How to validate if the sum of each polyhedron triangle's area multiplied by its normal is a vector with a magnitude of zero?

Tags: geometry

Lately me and a couple of friends have been working on a 3D physics simulation for static and dynamic pressure on polyhedra. I noticed some strange behaviour from my static pressure simulation. Normally, if a polyhedron is completely submerged in the air, the net force produced by the static pressure should have a magnitude of zero (the air pressure is equal on every triangle). However, this is not always the case. Some imported meshes (you can think of them as polyhedra) like a surf board do not behave as expected, since they produce a net force that has a bigger magnitude than zero.

My approach of calculating the net force caused by the static pressure on a polyhedron is to go through its triangles and calculate the force for every one of them. My hypothesis is that the following formula should be true for every polyhedron.

My hypothesis is that $|\sum_{i=0}^{k}A_{i}n_{i}|=0$ for every polyhedron, where
k is the number of triangles, A is the area and n is the normal vector.

Unfortunately, this does not always seem to happen, so either my hypothesis is incorrect or something strange is going on with some imported meshes. The problem is that I have no idea of how to validate my hypothesis for every possible polyhedron.

Comment: My question is now updated with the usage of the word polyhedron instead of polygon.

Comment: Your hypothesis is correct. Applying divergence theorem for vectors $\vec{F}=\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$ one can show that every component of vector $\sum A_i\vec{n}_i$ is equal to zero. Possible source of errors: numerical inaccuracy (is your non-zero force greater than precision?), incorrect normal vector direction (it should be or outward or inward for all faces) or physical problem statement which is nonrelevant to your hypothesis, for example if your meshed body is moving or streamlined, you cannot expect that air pressure is constant and that there is no tangential force.

Comment: Another possible cause of error: Perhaps the meshes are *not* polyhedra after all? For example with the surfboard, the creator may have designed the board itself and some attached fin separately; they should have removed the common, glued faces from both parts, but perhaps removed them only from one.

Comment: Thank you for laying eyes on my hypothesis! I will look into the validity of the triangle normals and the quality of imported meshes. My question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

When you say “area times normal”, that sounds very much like cross product to me. If you have points $a,b,c$ in space then $\frac12(b-a)\times(c-a)$ will have magnitude equal to the area of the triangle between the three points, and direction normal to that triangle.

If you do the computation of the cross product one coordinate at a time, you find that e.g. the first coordinate of the cross product only depends on the second and third coordinate of the points. So you can make a statement about the first coordinate of the mesh by just looking at the projection of the mesh into the $yz$-plane. The magnitude of the first cross product coordinate for a single triangle is proportional to the area of that projected triangle. Likewise for the other dimensions.

If you project your whole mesh into the plane, and it is a convex polyhedron, then each part of the plane will be covered by two triangles, one from the top and one from the bottom of the polyhedron, so to speak. If the polyhedron is not convex, you might have four or more triangles covering some areas, but it should always be an even number: as many triangles facing up as down.

If all your triangles in space are oriented consistently, either all the normals pointing outwards or all pointing in, then in the projection the two triangles covering any part of the projection plane would have opposite orientation. Their areas would cancel out, since they would contribute equal magnitude but opposite sign to the sum. Thus you get a net zero.

This might be a possible cause for your observed non-zero meshes: perhaps some of your triangles are flipped the wrong way? Or it could be numeric imprecision.